# video element with controls stops propagation of touch events

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

If we set controls attribute on video

```
<video src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" controls></video>
```

it stops propagation of touch events. Why is that happens, and is there a way to fix this?
http://jsfiddle.net/HptdV/

Answer (score 0):

`ontouchstart event` isn't supported in most of the desktop browsers as it is for (iphone/tablet) [see documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/touchstart).

That's why the fiddle don't show the alert.

As you can see in the [UPDATE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HptdV/11/) without the `controls` the alert is not fired as well.

If you want to control the video you can do it this way [html5 audio api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video)

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LdJ7C/)

```
<video id="demo" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg"></video>
<div>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').play()">Play the Audio</button>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').pause()">Pause the Audio</button>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').volume+=0.1">Increase Volume</button>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').volume-=0.1">Decrease Volume</button>
</div>
```